# Firefox making CSS Rules up?

Tags: css, firefox

This is what I see on the inspector:

[image: Firefox Inspector]

There's like a left highlight in two rules, which are the ones Firefox is making up,
if I look on the computed styles I see this:

[image: Computed Styles]

And finally this is how the original CSS looks like:

[image: Raw CSS]

So Firefox it's changing the position and width rules somehow.

Anyone can explain me why is this happening and how to avoid Firefox changing those rules? 
(In Chrome, Safari works fine)

Comment: Developer tools are explicitly designed to show the actual CSS (and HTML) on display, not the original static code received from the server (which is still available in the "Net" pane or good old *View Source* menu). Don't you have some JavaScript code as well?

Comment: Not any that changes that specific element

Answer (score 0):

The "left highlight" is used to indicate a style rule that has been modified within the Developer Toolbar since the page loaded. Reloading the page and/or restarting the browser should repair the rules from your stylesheet.

If you're still encountering the issue after this "quick fix", my next advice is to search your stylesheet(s) for `position: absolute`, disable them one at a time, and re-test. It's very unlikely Firefox is changing your style rules on its own.

You might also find it easier to postpone minifying your CSS while you're debugging. That way you'll get more useful line numbers to reference vs. having every rule cited as being on `master.css:1`.

Finally, you might find it advantageous to use [shallow selectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn194516.aspx) in your CSS rather than deeply nested selectors like the one you've shown. This will help avoid [specificity conflicts](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), which was likely the original cause of the issue you're encountering.

Comment: What could be more specific that a rule with two ids? Anyway both things (the minimization and the nesting) are because I'm using less. That doesn't explain the changed rules tho.